# Change widget in Row based on Navigation selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Scaffold and with a row in its body.

```
class StudentsView extends StatelessWidget {
  const StudentsView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context)) const SideNavigation(),
          if (someCondition) const StudentsPanel(),
          else (someOtherCondition) const SomeOtherPanel(),
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView(
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      'Preview Panel',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The side navigation widget looks like so

```
class SideNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideNavigation({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SideNavigation> createState() => _SideNavigationState();
}

class _SideNavigationState extends State<SideNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationRail(
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onDestinationSelected: _onItemTapped,
      extended: Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? true : false,
      destinations: const [
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: Text('Item1'),
        ),
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: Text('Item2'),
        ),
      ]
    )
```

How do I bubble the item selected in the NavigationRail back up to the Scaffold to show `SomeOtherPanel()` instead of `StudentsPanel()`? The `_onItemTapped` function only changes the local `_selectedIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you are asking about state management and widget communication, years ago I wrote an article about that: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

You can also achieve this using a state management package like provider, riverpod, bloc , etc.

For this example I'll just use callbacks (to communicate the child with the parent widget).

1- Convert your `StudentsView` to Stateful to refresh the widget state.
2- Create a callback in `SideNavigation` to know when the item is selected.
3- Add the callback param in your parent widget to receive the value and refresh the state.

Full example (you can change the conditions of course):

```dart
class StudentsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StudentsView({super.key});

  @override
  State<StudentsView> createState() => _StudentsViewState();
}

class _StudentsViewState extends State<StudentsView> {

  bool someCondition = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context)) SideNavigation(
            onItemSelected: (index){
              if(index == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  someCondition = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  someCondition = false;
                });
              }
            }
          ),
          if (someCondition) const StudentsPanel(),
          else const SomeOtherPanel(),
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView(
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      'Preview Panel',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class SideNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideNavigation({
    required this.onItemSelected,
    super.key,
  });

  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  @override
  State<SideNavigation> createState() => _SideNavigationState();
}

class _SideNavigationState extends State<SideNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    widget.onItemSelected(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationRail(
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onDestinationSelected: _onItemTapped,
      extended: Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? true : false,
      destinations: const [
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: Text('Item1'),
        ),
        NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: Text('Item2'),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```